# MSSQL two tables compare specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MSSQL I have two tables with same columns (structure of table is same).

I want to compare data from first table and second table. I just want to compare specific row example where ID=5. Then I want that sql show me just column/s and values where value is different.

Example:

```
First table:

ID  ----- NUMBER ------YEAR ------- VEHICLE_ID

5**********22**********2017*************5
```

Second table:

```
ID  ----- NUMBER ------YEAR ------- VEHICLE_ID

5***********28*********2017************7
```

Expected result:

```
---- NUMBER --- VEHICLE_ID
   22           5

   28           7
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Add some more sample data.

Comment: You only want the columns that have changed is that correct? So in your example if the year in the first table was 2016 you would expect the result to include a year column as well?

Answer (score 0):

This does work fine. Maybe there's a better way.

```
DECLARE @First TABLE (
    ID INT
    , NUMBER INT
    , VEHICLE_ID INT
    );

DECLARE @Second TABLE (
    ID INT
    , NUMBER INT
    , VEHICLE_ID INT
    );

INSERT INTO @First (ID, NUMBER, VEHICLE_ID)
VALUES (5, 22, 7);

INSERT INTO @Second (ID, NUMBER, VEHICLE_ID)
VALUES (5, 28, 7);

SELECT T.NUMBER, T.VEHICLE_ID
FROM (
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.NUMBER, T1.VEHICLE_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT F.ID, F.NUMBER, F.VEHICLE_ID
        FROM @First AS F
        EXCEPT
        SELECT S.ID, S.NUMBER, S.VEHICLE_ID
        FROM @Second AS S
        ) AS T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.NUMBER, T2.VEHICLE_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT S.ID, S.NUMBER, S.VEHICLE_ID
        FROM @Second AS S
        EXCEPT
        SELECT F.ID, F.NUMBER, F.VEHICLE_ID
        FROM @First AS F
        ) AS T2
    ) AS T
WHERE T.ID = 5;
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ NUMBER ║ VEHICLE_ID ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║     22 ║          7 ║
║     28 ║          7 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

Inner `EXCEPT` statements find differences between two tables, `UNION ALL` merges them into one table as you want. Then I just filter by ID.

There must be a more elegant way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
select number,vehicle_id from
(select number,vehicle_id,id from first_table
union all
select number,vehicle_id,id from Second_table) a
where id=5
```